# D3 JS with JSON

Tags: json, api, d3.js

I'm working on trying to make a data visualization with D3 and the openweather API to try to visualize temperatures around the world in bar form from major cities.

I have the following query:

```
d3.json("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=192710,2643743,1850147,2988507,524901,5368361,1816670,2177052,1835847,3128760,7533612,292223,7870410,3451190,1275339,4904381,5856195,&units=metric", function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```

For reference here is a link to the data in JSON so you can read it as well.

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=192710,2643743,1850147,2988507,524901,5368361,1816670,2177052,1835847,3128760,7533612,292223,7870410,3451190,1275339,4904381,5856195,&units=metric

The first object appears to be the count (cnt) while the next object is another array with each of the objects(cities) that I have queried. I am specifically trying to access those temperature values. Which key or name would I reference to get the respective temperature (temp) value?

As I understand it, data.cnt returns the first object, but data.list returns nothing and am confused as to how to access this JSON's properties.

Comment: You'll access it when using your data variable as a data object for a D3 selection.  There are many tutorials on d3 that should get you started. http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would get you started:

```
var countriesAndTemps = [];
d3.json("...",function(data)
{
  // Access the list of countries
  data.list.forEach(function(datum)
  {
    var countryInfo =
    {
      temperature : datum.main.temp,
      name        : datum.sys.country
     }
   }
}
```